# sql constraint violation exception

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity Mathematics referenced by MathematicsAnswer. If a perform a post request on Mathematics, I get the exception that  field on MathsAnswer cannot be null. But I actually did cascade on the field. Please I need solution this.
`java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'question_id' cannot be null`

sql schema:

```
CREATE TABLE MATHEMATICS(
id integer not null auto_increment,
year date not null,
question_no int not null,
question varchar(128) default null,
primary key(id)
) engine=InnoDb;

CREATE TABLE MATHS_ANSWER(
id integer not null auto_increment,
date date default null,
question_no int not null,
question_id int not null,
solution varchar(128) default null,
solution_url varchar(128) default null,
primary key(id),
foreign key(question_id) references MATHEMATICS(id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) engine = InnoDb;
```

entity class:

```
@Entity
        @Table(name = "Mathematics")
        public class Mathematics {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column(name = "year")
    private Date year;
    
    @Column(name = "question_no")
    private Integer questionNo;
    
    @Column(name = "question")
    private String question;
    
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "maths", fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL
            )
    private MathsAnswers answers = new MathsAnswers();//getters & setters
```

MathsAnswers.java:

```
 @Entity
            @Table(name = "Mathematics")
            public class Mathematics {
    
        @Id
        @Column(name = "id")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
        private Integer id;
        
        @Column(name = "year")
        private Date year;
        
        @Column(name = "question_no")
        private Integer questionNo;
        
        @Column(name = "question")
        private String question;
        
        @OneToOne(mappedBy = "maths", fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL
                )
        private MathsAnswers answers = new MathsAnswers();//getters & setters
```

jpaRepo:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "mathematics", path = "maths")
public interface MathsRepo extends JpaRepository<Mathematics, Integer> {

}
```

post request:

```
{
    "year":"2004-01-03",
    "questionNo":"4",
    "question":"How many weeks makes a year?"
}
```

Comment: You added same entity twice instead of MathAnswers.java in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The table name specified for my `MathsAnswer` entity was wrong; should've been `Mathsanswer` instead of `Mathematics`.